# Using a non-anonymous callback function for jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would to use a callback function in the same 'class' when the ajax request is successful. Here's the code

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: ajax_url,
   success: this.callback
})

this.callback = function() {

  // ERROR! this doesn't point to the right context!
  this.run_some_process();

}
```

Are there any built-in JavaScript constructs that can allow me to get or save the correct context, without having to resort to [a custom delegate function?](http://www.terrainformatica.com/?p=9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `$.ajax's` ['context' option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly.

```
var that = this;

$.ajax({
   type: 'get',
   url: ajax_url,
   success: that.callback
})

that.callback = function() {
  // ERROR! this doesn't point to the right context!
  that.run_some_process();

}
```